# Create mySQL Table from multiple mySQL tables; adding together identical columns and appending varchars

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a more exotic SQL statement I'm trying to perform which "combines" 3 tables as a cartesion product and adds together the identical columns.

I've simplified this as much as possible.  Say I've made three tables as such, which will then be combined to make table_d:

```
mysql>select * from table_a;
Code  Goat Dog Cat
A 4 5 6
B 7 8 9
C 10 11 12

mysql>select * from table_b;
Code  Goat Dog Cat
D 1 2 3
E 4 5 6
F 7 8 9

mysql>select * from table_c;
Code  Goat Dog Cat Bird
T 1 1 1 2
Y 2 2 2 3
U 3 3 3 4
```

An SQL create table statement, along the lines of "create table table_d as (select..." then makes a table like below.

Here the identically named columns are added together while the Code field is built up as a concatenated string.  However I'm not sure how to go about this.

Thus

```
mysql>select * from table_d;
Code  Goat Dog Cat Bird
ADT 6 8 10 2
ADY 7 9 11 3
ADU 8 10 12 4
BDT 9 11 13 2  
BDY .....
....
....
CFU 20 22 24 4
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated at this point.  This will also be performed on more than 3 tables at once but I showed only 3 here for simplicity.  Thanks!

SQL Insertion code:::

```
create table table_a(code varchar(1),goat integer, dog integer, cat integer);
create table table_b(code varchar(1),goat integer, dog integer, cat integer);
create table table_c(code varchar(1),goat integer, dog integer, cat integer, bird integer);
insert into table_a values('A','4','5','6');
insert into table_a values('B','7','8','9');
insert into table_a values('C','10','11','12');
insert into table_b values('D','1','2','3');
insert into table_b values('E','4','5','6');
insert into table_b values('F','7','8','9');
insert into table_c values('T','1','1','1','2');
insert into table_c values('Y','2','2','2','3');
insert into table_c values('U','3','3','3','4');
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Did you try this and have a problem? Research "Cartesian Product" or "Cartesian Join" if you're having trouble getting started. Once you get all the tables joined you'll need to have a lot of calculated columns.

Comment: Yeah the cartesian however, at least those that I try, just expand as additional fields rather than combine.  I tried to reword the question a little. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_d
SELECT CONCAT(a.code, b.code, c.code) AS CODE, (a.goat + b.goat + c.goat) AS goat, (a.dog + b.dog + c.dog) AS dog, (a.cat + b.cat + c.cat) AS cat
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b
JOIN table_c c
ORDER BY CODE;
```

Comment: This certainly works.  You understand the problem.  It would be extremely labor intensive to make a statement for all the tables this must be done across however.  Automatic field recognition would be more beneficial.

Comment: And a good example of why this is so is because your example misses "Bird" from table_c. :)

Comment: I can't think of any solution using pure SQL off the top of my head, but generating the statement using any programming language should be trivial.  You can run *DESCRIBE [tableName]* to grab the fields then generate the query.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting into trouble because your column schema varies from table to table across a partitioned dataset. Relational DBs really prefer rows to columns when structure fluctuates. What about a more row-oriented model, like:

```
mysql>select * from table_a;
Code Type Number
A Goat 4
A Dog 5
A Cat 6
B Goat 7
B Dog 8
B Cat 9
C Goat 10
C Dog 11
C Cat 12
```

If you joined the tables with themselves multiple times then you would be able to use SUM() aggregate functions to do your counts rather than using calculated columns.