# select matching data from multiple mysql tables+version 5.0

Tags: mysql

I have very limited knowledge of Mysql and queries as my db was set up for me and I being left to run the site.  I have need of only one query and have spent hours trying to adapt a statement that would perform as needed.  Hope someone is willing to do this. My db admin is now only my host.

Mysql version 5.0 has two tables that I work with.

Table A (very large) has the following columns:

SpeciesID - Normal - Latin - Category - Code - View - CAAB - ITIS

Table B (small table) has the following columns:

Normal - Latin - Category - Code - View - CAAB - ITIS

I want to find the matches from table A and table B and create a table C containing those matches with Latin and SpeciesID only.

I know I need a join in the statement and maybe a match but have not been able to work them out at all.

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: Which columns are you matching between the two tables? Which columns should be put in Table C?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give the code you had tried, desired output example with initial data example and more specified error or problem, not just "i want ....."

Comment: similar questions you can look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292313/create-a-new-table-from-merging-two-tables-with-union... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862178/create-mysql-table-from-multiple-mysql-tables-adding-together-identical-columns...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (SpeciesId, Latin)
SELECT A.SpeciesId, A.Latin FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
ON A.Normal = B.Normal AND A.Latin = B.Latin AND
A.Category = B.Category AND A.Code = B.Code AND
A.CAAB - B.CAAB AND A.ITIS = B.ITIS;
```

Comment: The code returns a 0. This is the exact code I then used which also returned 0.  INSERT INTO table3 (SpeciesId, Latin)
SELECT A.SpeciesId, A.Latin FROM species A
INNER JOIN ASFIS2 B
ON A.Normal = B.Normal AND A.Latin = B.Latin AND
A.Category = B.Category AND A.Code = B.Code AND
A.View = B.View AND A.CAAB - B.CAAB AND
A.ITIS = B.ITIS;    There are exact matches and different lines in table A

Comment: Thank you, I got this statement to work;

INSERT INTO table3 (SpeciesId, Latin)
SELECT A.SpeciesId, A.Latin FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
ON A.Normal = B.Normal;

but returns a 0 count when I use the AND term listing all 7 columns.